# Why bash+awk script produces error?

Tags: bash, awk

I have simple script:

```
#!/bin/sh
column=$1
awk '{print $'$column'}'
```

When I run:

```
ls -la | ./Column.sh
```

I receive:

```
awk: {print $}
awk:         ^ syntax error
```

Why? All seems correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not very clear what you want the script to do.

The cause of this error is that you are not passing any arguments to the script. As a result `$1` is empty.

You need to pass the column number that you want to print:

```
ls -la | ./Column.sh 1
```

Will print the permissions column which is in column 1.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing an argument to Column.sh, so $1 is the empty string.  Perhaps you meant to do:

```
ls -a | while read name; do ./Column.sh $name; done
```

Answer (score 0):

awk has a facility to pass shell variables into awk so you don't have to play quoting games with your awk script:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk -v "column=${1:-1}" '{print $column}'
```

I use the shell's "default value" mechanism to provide a default value of 1 if no parameter is given.